# Android Webview on ICS (Ice Cream Sandwich)

Tags: android, webview

Webview on ICS looks lile buggy. Below code show nothing on 2.x emulators but half page white screen on ICS emulators. Below layout is for test porpuses. If I put some html to render inside webview on ICS it shows nothing for half page then continue like it has rendered the half but I see only white empty area.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</WebView>    

</LinearLayout>
```

Has anybody an idea?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you should either make webview fill_parent (or match_parent), or give width and height, im not sure, but guess it will not be very smart "wraping to content" as webview content is difficult to measure.

That said, I have thousands of problems with webview on ICS: No refreshing windows, Hardware acceleration causing all kind of artifacts, problems with iframes, screen flickering, browser crashing on CSS3 animations, etc etc. Most of these problems are new on ICS, while others like Hardware Acceleration are not new, but have worsen noticeabily.

Answer (score 0):

I'm encountering the same problem, or at least a very similar one.  What I have is a WebView that is centered horizontally when in landscape and fills the vertical space.  The WebView is being positioned correctly, but it seems like the region of the screen that is actually rendered is aligned to the left side of the screen, but with the same width of the WebView.  This causes only part of the WebView to render with the rest showing as the background color.  So there does seem to be a bug of some kind in 4.0, as it works perfectly fine on the 2.3 and 3.2 devices I've tested it on.